# typescript deep keyof when field is an option

Tags: typescript, type-inference, keyof

I create an function to select and keyof of deep object.
but I don't know why this keyof on my object is not work when it is an option.

```js
type Database = {
    User?: {
        id: string
        name: string
    },
    Post?: {   // if i remove ? it work but it should be an option
        id: string
        content: string
    }
}

type SelectQuery<T> = {
    [Table in keyof T]?: {
        select: {
            [field in keyof T[Table]]?: boolean
        }
    }
}


function select(query: SelectQuery<Database>) {}

select({
    Post: {
        select: {
          // it should suggest content and id here

        
        }
    }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgQxAgRggzrAvDA3sGQmAVUwCcB+ALjwKPoEsATG9EMhgOwHM77DOCALZRW7Lr3oBfADR8YABQD2baniIB6DTAYAzHTDJQhSgG6wKOkDADuSsgGsYKAK7WG19AAslLgDZMzrAInDBKECAMSpzyjCwwbBw8sUQAxtEgUJwgYkmSRFLAhaCQsADKUH5QqSAAii5QZGAAPAAqAHwwOPj0ANqtqFU6oQ5QYEr6rQC6aj38hJhVNTRz8326DJWBXDCj45P9g1BTMzQoSkpVISmEhdJFwI+6Lpw1UaGL1SAAFACODU0aBUlnUAS1EMg0Jh2gBKPDFT41b6rRQqHK0NYJSpfFY3TTaDwJHz+QLoFzcbhQdBsGDpbJZawhbaBLyNKCPTF4u4FIowoA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have nested optional fields in your `Database` type and when you access one table you get a type `tableFields | undefined` and `keyof` returns `never` for this case. Example:

```
// never
type Case1 = keyof Database['Post']
```

To fix this issue you can use built-in [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type:

```
// "id" | "content"
type Case2 = keyof NonNullable<Database['Post']>
```

Usage:

```
type SelectQuery<T> = {
  [Table in keyof T]?: {
    select: {
      [field in keyof NonNullable<T[Table]>]?: boolean;
    };
  };
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnaBeKBvAUFKAVXQCcB+ALh3wKgEsATK1YEugOwHMBuGg9uAFsIzVhx40AvrwIAFAPYtK1WlAD0a+gDN6UEhEHyAbtDL1gUAO7ySAayhIArhboXUAC3mOANgwfQ4dih5MGA6eXY+eiYoFjYuGVoAYwjgCHZgUXiJAmlcPNxQSCgAZQhvCCTgAEVHCBIQAB4AFQA+KCw8AgBtZuQK+iDbCBB5HWaAXWUu2nQKqqoZ1W6tOnK-Dihh0Z0AOQjdn29+iBbek4nWqaokeXkKwMTcxLyCrUd2KvCgucrgAAoAI51BpUMrzGogprwRAodCtACUOEkuFwvyq-xmChYiyi6MyKlU6k0rlinh8flQjk4nAgqBYUBSGXSFkCGz87nqECikgANFJ+ZIEbxcEA)